# Fatal error: Index out of range (Swift 3, Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a guessing game app, written in Swift and using Firebase as my PaaS. The app builds, and the function below works when I test it in a Swift playground, but when I run the app, I get the following error message:

> fatal error: Index out of range

Xcode tells me that the offending code is the `randomKey = myArray[randomIndex]` line. I'm new to Swift and not very familiar with Xcode's debugging tools yet. I've tested printing the `count` and `randomIndex` to the console and every time, `randomIndex` < `count` as expected. The `print("The random key is...` line also successfully prints to the console before the fatal error is thrown.

I've checked other SO articles related to this error and haven't been able to apply them to my issue.

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
var movieArray = [String]()
var randomIndex : Int = 0
var randomKey = ""

    func randomKeyfromFIR () -> String {
        var count = 0
        movieRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for movie in snapshot.children {
                let movies = movie as! FIRDataSnapshot
                count = Int(movies.childrenCount)
                movieArray.append(movies.key)
                randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
                randomKey = movieArray[randomIndex]
                print("** The random key is... " + randomKey + " **")
            }

        return randomKey
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Definitely wouldn't have made it this far without lots of SO.

**UPDATE**

Because I was assigning value to `randomKey` and `randomIndex` inside the `for` loop I was getting multiple random numbers and different length arrays. Moved it outside and now it's working.

Comment: your count comes from movies.childrenCount but you're looking into movieArray for the lookup. You need to make sure randomIndex is less than the movieArray size.

Comment: Thanks. I added an extra line to show `movieArray.count`, and commented out the `randomKey = movieArray[randomIndex]` line and realized that it was printing out `count` times, so my code was generating multiple random numbers and different length arrays. I guess I need to get a better handle on how `.observeSingleEvent` works for Firebase.

Comment: Sure enough, moving everything after `movieArray.append(movies.key)` outside of the `for` loop has everything working as expected! Thanks again.